# C++ Reimplementing assignable "at()" function of vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

### What i discovered

I discover that C++ `vector::at()` is an assignable function, how is it possible?

I mean I can call `at()` function to get the value of vector at certain position, and i can assign a value to a certain position of the vector.

```cpp
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(5);
    vec.push_back(6);

    //get val at position
    cout << vec.at(0)<<endl; //it print 4

    //set val at position
    vec.at(0) = 89;
    std::cout << vec.at(0)<<endl; //it print 89
```

### What I want to do

I want to reimplement in my own vector class without inherit it or copy the original class; how can i do it?

```cpp
class myIntVector
{
    int arraye[50] = {0};
    
    //other class function and constructor
public:
    int at(int index)
    {
        //some code
    }
};
```

Comment: it returns `int&`

Comment: It is possible because `at()` returns a reference (to the value_type).

Comment: `vector.at(foo)` is the same as `vector[foo]`, it's just that `at` will throw an exception if `foo >= size()` while `[]` wont.

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, `vector[foo]` with `foo` out of range is undefined so it _may_ throw an exception in some implementations.

Comment: You'll need to adjust your return type slightly to return a _reference_ to the int that you would want to be modified by doing `vec.at(0) = 89;`  Make this change:  `int& at(int index)`  note the `&`.  and you can `return arraye[index];`  You'll want to learn about _lvalues_ and _rvalues_.  `arraye[index]` is an _lvalue_ because it refers to an object but an _rvalue_ like `89` is just a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to reimplement in my own vector class without inherit it or copy the original class; how can i do it?

Not trying to sound too snarky but you could read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at):

> **Return value**
>
> Reference to the requested element.

Therefore something like this:

```
class myIntVector
{
    int arraye[50] = {0};
    
    //other class function and constructor
public:
    int& at(int index)
    {
        return arraye[index];
    }
};
```

Also your indices should be `std::size_t`, and `std::array` is preferred to C-style arrays.

Comment: Does it work because the function become a pointer to what it returns or because who wrote the c++ compiler has defined that to make a function assignable you have to add the reference operator?

Comment: @VLN I think you need a [good introductory book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/) on C++. What references are and how they work should be explained in all of them. The function doesn't become anything. There are no pointers involved. A function cannot be assignable. It is the result of the function call that can be assigned to (because it is a lvalue/reference which was initialized to refer to the vector element). This is also not compiler-dependent, but part of the standardized C++ language.

Comment: Perfectly the answer I was expecting. Thanks